# setState not setting the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good afternoon everyone!

I have a little problem, I have a function to add to the cart and when clicking, I wanted to change the fill property to true and then fill as soon as the icon is clicked, but my setState is not setting!

This is the function:

```
  const loggedToAddCart = useCallback(
    (brandName, productId, setChangeFillCart, changeFillCart) => {
      if (!uid) {
        setMessageToast('Register to save photos and see prices');
        setOpenToast(true);
        setChangeFillCart(false);
        return;
      }
      if (cartIds.includes(productId)) {
        setChangeFillCart(false);
        deleteFromCart(brandName, productId);
      } else {
        setChangeFillCart(true);
        console.log(changeFillCart);

        addToCart(brandName, productId);
      }
    },
    [cartIds],
  );
```

And that's her call:

```
<div onClick={() => loggedToAddCart(brandName, productId, setChangeFillCart, changeFillCart)}>

 <Icon type="shoppingBag" size={24} strokeWidth={1} fill={cartIds.includes(productId) || changeFillCart} />

</div>
```

The setChangeFillCart and changeFillCart are coming via the properties of a fetch and I map them.
That console.log of else always shows that the value is false, even after its set, what could it be?

I thank you for your attention, hugs!

Answer (score 0):

`changeFillCart` is a local variable. It's probably defined with a `const`, and even if it's a `let` it's never going to change anyway. `setChangeFillCart` does not attempt to change your local variables. Putting a log statement where you did is only ever going to log out what `changeFillCart` was equal to when `loggedToAddCart` was created

The purposes of `setChangeFillCart` is to tell react to rerender the component. When that second render happens, a new local variable will be created which will get the new value. This variable is visible to anything created on that second render, not to things created on the first render. So if you want to see the new value, put your log statement in the body of the component so you can see what value it's rerendering with.

Comment: If I just want to change the cartSelected onClick, why something like this is not working?

<div
                      onClick={() => {
                        loggedToAddCart(brandName, productId);
                        cartSelected = true;
                      }}
                    >
                      {cartSelected ? 1 : 0}
                      <Icon type="shoppingBag" size={24} strokeWidth={1} fill={cartIds.includes(productId) || cartSelected} />
                    </div>

Comment: What is `cartSelected`? a piece of state? it wasn't in your question, and your comment doesn't show where it's declared.

Answer (score 0):

Your setState should be setting actually, I'll demonstrate it in a few steps and how to debug your issue in a sane matter, to help you fix this issue and in future cases...

Let's look at a practical example. Start by looking at the following:

```
export default function App() {
  const [foobar, setFoobar] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    setFoobar("One")
    console.log("[foobar]: ", foobar)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("[foobar]: ", foobar)
  }, [foobar])

  const foobarHandler = useCallback((setFoobar, foobar) => {
    setFoobar("third")
    console.log(foobar)
  })

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setFoobar("two")}>click</button>
      <button onClick={() => foobarHandler(setFoobar, foobar)}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Which outputs the following on load:

```
[foobar]:  
undefined
[foobar]:  
undefined
[foobar]:  One
```

If you click the first CTA:

```
[foobar]:  two
```

and after, the second CTA, you get:

```
two 
[foobar]:  third
```

If you click the second CTA again, you get:

```
third
```

When the application first runs, the `useEffect` is executed and you get `undefined`. Followed by `[foobar]:  One`!

This happens because the `foobar` state is not assigned a value in the `useState()` on the first run (componentDidMount).

You see the output `[foobar]:  One` because of the `useEffect` that has the dependency `foobar`, which runs every time `foobar` is updated! It acts as a watcher.

See the state flow here? How handy the `useEffect` can be to `watch` for state changes? It's useful to debug and you should use as such too!

Finally, the order matters, so when the second CTA is pressed you see the output of the `console.log(foobar)` that outputs the value in memory that at this time is `two`, followed immediately by the `useEffect` that executes changes because it watches `foobar` just like the first case I've exposed about `[foobar]:  One`.

```
  <button onClick={() => foobarHandler(setFoobar, foobar)}>click</button>
```

For this particular case, when you call `foobarHandler`, you are passing `foobar` that has `two` and in the last call `three` in the outer scope. In this context (inside the foobarHandler), the `foobar` and `setFoobar` are not coupled.

Try to create a useEffect and add `changeFillCart` as a dependency, and run a console.log(changeFillCart) and you'll see it changes.